# Does this make me a disbeliever?

Tags: allah, muslim-practices

I’ve been having these doubts come across my mind lately and it hasn’t been going away so I searched a question online. I was trying to look for answers to get rid of these doubts and strengthen my faith but now I feel guilty, does this make me a kafr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am being fully honest with you I am not sure but listen this is called waswas this is the whispers of shaitan saying this and you are not held accountable for these thoughts and in fact allah will reward you for dealing with these thoughts. But since you looked it up I am not sure but do not worry  when you fear Allah, you run to him go to him and repent use strong words to say how sorry you are and promise never to do it again. When you get waswas you say “ audhubillah minash shaitan rajeem.” Then turn to your left and spit 3 times not literally spit just whisper puu puu I guess and now you are fighting back from shaitan’s whispers. Allah forgives all sins but you must make taubah, be sincere in your repentance. Allah knows best.